# WCF DataService with EF CTP 5 CodeOnly DbContext

Tags: wcf, odata, entity-framework-ctp5

I am trying to build a WCF DataService on top of a Code Only `DbContext`. However as soon as I add the first `DbSet` property to my `DbContext` I get "Request Error" when accessing the .svc.

All I need to get the error is to have this `DbContext`:

```
public class JukeboxContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

and then do a basic WCF DataService based on it, and the error happens when i run the service.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Comment: Are you sure that your JukeboxContext with Songs set works? Request error can be just generic error because of problem with EF itself.

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that. I am using it directly with no problems - it is only when I access the service I have problems.

Comment: I added:[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] to get a better exception and it says:

Comment: The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'On data context type 'JukeboxContext', there is a top IQueryable property 'Songs' whose element type is not an entity type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to ignore this property.'. See server logs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Turnes out the exception means that it can't resolve which field is the primary key.
The easy way to go is to name it ID or ID - otherwise the DataServiceKey attribute will let you use composite keys